# Why was question about erasing SSD closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question

[Restoring the oxide layer of the NAND in a SSD to restore performance](https://superuser.com/questions/417077/ssd-erasing-to-boost-performance)

was closed a not a real question. I'm really unclear on why. It does not seem to be

> ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical

---

*Update:* I have edited the question to emphasize the distinction between what the question is about and TRIM.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with this question, as I see it, is, it's hard to understand what the person is talking about.

I admit that this seems to be because I simply don't know enough about the topic, but then maybe this is the wrong audience for the question in the first place?

Nevertheless, if you want to improve the question to make it more clear what is being asked, then I'd be happy to reopen.

---

#### Earlier Answer

> Funny thing, it is because electrons are captured in the oxide layer of the cells. This slows performance, but can be "reset" by applying larger voltage in the opposite direction of the cells to remove the electrons that block the cells.

Read that, then read it again, then read it until you understand why the question was closed :P

In all seriousness, what the user claims there *sounds* wrong. Which might be because he doesn't know what he's talking about. Which isn't surprising, cause neither do I.

- How are electrons *captured* in oxide layers?
- Where are these oxide layers in the SSD?
- How do you apply a voltage in a *direction*?
- How do you determine the opposite direction of a charge?

I have no clue what process he is trying to describe here and why he thinks it has to be explained on this level.

And then he asks for a *software hack*... What is that even?

The question is horrible. It could be made into a proper question that asks "*What is the TRIM feature and how do I enable it?*". But, in my opinion, it's not even clear if that's what the user is talking about. So you can't even edit the question in that regard.

Comment: I do understand perfectly the process he is talking about, and it has nothing to do with TRIM. Admittedly, the way to reset the oxide layer he is talking about would not be a good idea, but wouldn't the right response be an answer which says as much, not to vote to close the question as not a real question?

Comment: @MrAlpha: OK, then it's how I feared it could be - I just don't have a clue :D If you could maybe edit the question to be a bit more clear/structured, then I'd be happy to vote to reopen.

Comment: @MrAlpha Mind explaining in your question what exactly he's talking about? Sounds like TRIM to me...

Comment: @Kyle There is an oxide layer surrounding the floating gate in a NAND cell. This is what traps the electrons and makes NAND non-volatile. You write/erase NAND by applying strong voltage to pull electron in/out of the floating gate, through the oxide layer. This damages the oxide, breaking molecular bonds. These broken bonds can latch onto electrons passing through, over time giving the oxide layer an negative charge. This is what causes NAND to wear out from writes.

Comment: @MrAlpha update the question... and add a source. The point is to stop people from going, "he's talking about trim so this is a duplicate"

Comment: So I cleaned up the question to emphasize the distinction between what the question is about and TRIM.

Comment: @MrAlpha: Voted to reopen. Good job.